# What does [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]

Tags: c#, mef

What does [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)] mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To add to Julien's answer, I think conceptually you can think of it as [a Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Answer (score 20):

It means that, when requesting an instance of a class decorated with `[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]`, the [`CompositionContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.compositioncontainer.aspx) will always return the same instance of this class and not create a new one.

```
[Export]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
class Foo
{

}
```

The above class will give the following result:

```
private void Test()
{
  var foo1 = Container.GetExportedValue<Foo>();
  var foo2 = Container.GetExportedValue<Foo>();
  Console.WriteLine(foo1 == foo2); // => True
}
```

Comment: I can get around that by adding [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)] but it also brings up a few more issues. Such as object lifecycle. When do these objects get disposed?

Comment: Consider IRegionMemberLifeTime.KeepAlive as well.

Comment: Is there a way to do this using MEF2?