# What is the equivalent of MEFs CreationPolicy.NonShared in Ninject

Tags: ninject, mef

I know that **CreationPolicy.Shared** means **singleton**, as explained in here in [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557039/what-does-partcreationpolicycreationpolicy-shared) question.

So what about NonShared?

Should I have something like this?

```
Bind<IDataRepositoryFactory>().To<DataRepositoryFactory>().InTransientScope();
```

Or should I leave it without any scope like

```
Bind<IDataRepositoryFactory>().To<DataRepositoryFactory>();
```

What is the difference between the above two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default scope in Ninject is Transient, which effectively means a new instance will be created every time one is requested, so there is no difference between your two examples.

[More on Ninject scopes here](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes):

- Transient - A new instance of the type will be created each time one is requested. This is the default scope if none is specified.
- Singleton - Only a single instance of the type will be created, and the same instance will be returned for each subsequent request.
- Thread - One instance of the type will be created per thread.
- Request - One instance of the type will be created for each Web Request. See the Ninject.Web.Common InRequestScope article for more information before using this.
- Named, Call, Parent - Supplied by an extension. See Ninject.Extensions.NamedScope extension for more information before using this.
- Custom - You can also easily define your own scopes using the .InScope(Func selectScope) method.